# Reading a specific part of a text file using Batch

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have a .h file that contains these lines, from line 8 to line 23:

```
#define SW_VERSION_BYTE_14          '0'
#define SW_VERSION_BYTE_13          '1'
#define SW_VERSION_BYTE_12          '5'
#define SW_VERSION_BYTE_11          '.'
#define SW_VERSION_BYTE_10          '0'
#define SW_VERSION_BYTE_9           '0'
#define SW_VERSION_BYTE_8           '5'
#define SW_VERSION_BYTE_7           '.'
#define SW_VERSION_BYTE_6           '0'
#define SW_VERSION_BYTE_5           '0'
#define SW_VERSION_BYTE_4           '0'
#define SW_VERSION_BYTE_3           '.'
#define SW_VERSION_BYTE_2           '0'
#define SW_VERSION_BYTE_1           '0'
#define SW_VERSION_BYTE_0           '0' /* LSB */
```

I need the extract the #define'd numbers out of this file and save it in a variable so that:

```
var==015005000000
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are there any other lines in the file beginning with `#define SW_VERSION_BYTE_`? are they above the ones you show? And what have you tried on your own so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: "What should I do?"
A: "build a script..."

ok, to be serious:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "var="
for /f "tokens=2 delims='" %%a in ('type file.h ^|find "#define SW_VERSION_BYTE_"') do set "var=!var!%%a"
echo %var:.=%
```

Sadly, you didn't show the whole file, so this solution will work or not - depending on the other lines of your file.

Comment: Thank you that worked well for me. I prints "SW015005000000", I've removed the "SW" using this command:
%var:.=% | sed 's/SW//'
And now I need to add "rW" to the string to be "rW015005000000", then save it to a variable.
I'm sorry but I'm new to batch.

Comment: without using unix-tools (`sed`): add another substring substitution. Either `set "var=%var:SW=rW"` (if "SW" is fix) or remove first two chars and add "rW": `set "var=rW%var:~2"`

Comment: Where are the _from line 8 to line 23_ constraint included in this solution?